# Pop-up content after clicking on an item from the wpf list

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement this drop-down menu in WPF:

[image]

When you click on the number of the question, it should open additional content. I can't attach the code, because there is not even an approximate implementation. I tried to implement via `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`, `ListBox`, `StackPanel` but I just didn't have enough knowledge.

Here is the code I've tried:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
        <Button Content="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
        <Button Content="2"/>
    </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Add a User Control to your project.

[image]

Step 2: Name it Arrow.

[image]

Step 3: This Control will act as a drop-down arrow for us. Add the following XAML code to the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Question_Builder_App.Controls.Arrow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,5,0" Height="15" BorderBrush="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="10" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="135"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,5,0" BorderBrush="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="15" Width="10" Margin="0,11,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="225"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The control should look like this:

[image]

Step 4: Add the following XAML to your MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Builder_App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#FF283246">
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LeftPanel" Grid.Column="0">
        <Border CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF033B50" Margin="50,20,50,0">
            <Button x:Name="AddQuestion_BTN" FontSize="24" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10,0,10,0" Click="AddQuestion_BTN_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="RightPanel" Grid.Column="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

The designer should look like this:

[image]

Step 5: Now lets add some C# codes to our MainWindow:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Question_Builder_App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddSampleData("Test Button 1", "Test Button");
            AddSampleData("Test Button 2", "Test Button");
            AddSampleData("Test Button 3", "Test Button");
        }


    private int ButtonCount = 0;
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

    private class DataModel
    {
        public string MainButtonName { get; set; }
        public string PageName { get; set; }
        public Page DisplayPage { get; set; }
    }
    private static string CreateInputWindow(string WindowDescription)
    {
        Window ButtonInfoWindow = new Window();
        ButtonInfoWindow.Background = null; ButtonInfoWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
        Border TextDescription = AddBorder(WindowDescription, 24);
        TextBox TB = new TextBox();
        TB.MinWidth = 100; TB.FontSize = 24;
        Button B = new Button();
        B.FontSize = 24; B.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0); B.Content = "Set";
        B.Click += delegate { ButtonInfoWindow.Close(); };
        SP.Children.Add(TextDescription); SP.Children.Add(TB); SP.Children.Add(B);
        ButtonInfoWindow.Content = SP;
        ButtonInfoWindow.ShowDialog();
        return TB.Text;
    }

    private void AddQuestion_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border TopBorder = new Border();
        TopBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10); TopBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(3, 59, 80)); TopBorder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        TopBorder.Margin = new Thickness(40, 20, 40, 0);
        StackPanel TopSPPanel = new StackPanel();
        TopBorder.Child = TopSPPanel;
        StackPanel LowerPanel = new StackPanel();
        LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        string MainButtonName = CreateInputWindow("What is the name of the button you wish to create?");

        Border NewQuestion_BTN = AddBorder(ButtonCount + 1 + ". " + MainButtonName, 24);
        NewQuestion_BTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            if (LowerPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                NewQuestion_BTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(3, 59, 80));
            }
            else
            {
                LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                NewQuestion_BTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
        };
        TopSPPanel.Children.Add(NewQuestion_BTN);

        LowerPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10);
        Border LowerNewQuestion_BTN = AddBorder("+", 24);
        LowerNewQuestion_BTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            string InputText = CreateInputWindow("What is the name of the button you wish to create?");
            Border ChooseQuestionBTN = AddBorder(LowerPanel.Children.Count + ". " + InputText, 16);
            ChooseQuestionBTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
            {
                UncheckAllButtons();
                ChooseQuestionBTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
                NavigateToPage(MainButtonName, InputText);
            };
            LowerPanel.Children.Insert(LowerPanel.Children.Count - 1, ChooseQuestionBTN);
        };
        LowerPanel.Children.Add(LowerNewQuestion_BTN); TopSPPanel.Children.Add(LowerPanel);
        LeftPanel.Children.Insert(ButtonCount, TopBorder);
        ButtonCount++;
    }

    private void NavigateToPage(string MainButtonText, string NameChecker)
    {
        bool CheckIfToADDANewPage = true;

        foreach (DataModel PageFinder in PageCollection)
        {
            if (PageFinder.PageName == NameChecker && PageFinder.MainButtonName == MainButtonText)
            {
                RightPanel.Navigate(PageFinder.DisplayPage);
                CheckIfToADDANewPage = false;
            }
        }

        if (CheckIfToADDANewPage == true)
        {
            DataModel SavePage = new DataModel();
            SavePage.MainButtonName = MainButtonText; SavePage.PageName = NameChecker; SavePage.DisplayPage = CreateANewPage();
            PageCollection.Add(SavePage);
            RightPanel.Navigate(SavePage.DisplayPage);
        }

    }

    private static Page CreateANewPage()
    {
        Page QuestionPage = new Page();
        StackPanel QuestionPanel = new StackPanel();
        Border QuestionBorder = AddBorder("+", 24);
        QuestionBorder.Margin = new Thickness(5, 20, 0, 0); QuestionBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
        QuestionBorder.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            StackPanel UpperQuestionPanel = new StackPanel(); UpperQuestionPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            UpperQuestionPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
            Border QuestionNumberTXT = AddBorder(QuestionPanel.Children.Count.ToString(), 24);
            QuestionNumberTXT.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; QuestionNumberTXT.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
            Controls.Arrow PanelArrow = new Controls.Arrow();
            PanelArrow.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 10, 0); PanelArrow.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

            StackPanel InnerQuestionPanel = new StackPanel(); InnerQuestionPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; InnerQuestionPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 10, 0);
            PanelArrow.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
            {
                if (InnerQuestionPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    InnerQuestionPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    PanelArrow.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
                    PanelArrow.Margin = new Thickness(45, 20, 10, 0);
                    if (InnerQuestionPanel.ActualWidth < 1)
                    {
                        Border InnerQuestionBorder = AddBorder(CreateInputWindow("Please enter description of the question: "), 24);
                        InnerQuestionBorder.MaxWidth = 800;
                        InnerQuestionPanel.Children.Insert(0, InnerQuestionBorder);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    InnerQuestionPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    PanelArrow.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
                    PanelArrow.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 10, 0);
                }
            };

            WrapPanel NewQuestionWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
            NewQuestionWrapPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            Border AddNewQuestionBTN = AddBorder("+", 24);
            AddNewQuestionBTN.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
            AddNewQuestionBTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
            {
                NewQuestionWrapPanel.MaxWidth = InnerQuestionPanel.ActualWidth;
                Border ChooseNewQuestion = AddBorder(CreateInputWindow("Add new question: "), 24);
                ChooseNewQuestion.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
                NewQuestionWrapPanel.Children.Insert(NewQuestionWrapPanel.Children.Count - 1, ChooseNewQuestion);
            };

            NewQuestionWrapPanel.Children.Insert(NewQuestionWrapPanel.Children.Count, AddNewQuestionBTN); InnerQuestionPanel.Children.Add(NewQuestionWrapPanel);
            UpperQuestionPanel.Children.Add(QuestionNumberTXT); UpperQuestionPanel.Children.Add(PanelArrow); UpperQuestionPanel.Children.Add(InnerQuestionPanel);
            QuestionPanel.Children.Insert(QuestionPanel.Children.Count - 1, UpperQuestionPanel);
        };
        QuestionPanel.Children.Insert(QuestionPanel.Children.Count, QuestionBorder); QuestionPage.Content = QuestionPanel;
        return QuestionPage;
    }

    private static Border AddBorder(string InnerText, int SetFontSize)
    {
        Border NewBorder = new Border();
        NewBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10); NewBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(3, 59, 80)); NewBorder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        NewBorder.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
        TextBlock NewButton = new TextBlock();
        NewButton.FontSize = SetFontSize; NewButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch; NewButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        NewButton.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0);
        NewButton.Text = InnerText;
        NewButton.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        NewBorder.Child = NewButton;
        return NewBorder;
    }

    private void AddSampleData(string MainButtonText, string SecondaryButtonText)
    {
        Border TopBorder = new Border();
        TopBorder.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10); TopBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(3, 59, 80)); TopBorder.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        TopBorder.Margin = new Thickness(40, 20, 40, 0);
        StackPanel TopSPPanel = new StackPanel();
        TopBorder.Child = TopSPPanel;
        StackPanel LowerPanel = new StackPanel();
        LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        Border NewQuestion_BTN = AddBorder(ButtonCount + 1 + ". " + MainButtonText, 24);
        NewQuestion_BTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            if (LowerPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                NewQuestion_BTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(3, 59, 80));
            }
            else
            {
                LowerPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                NewQuestion_BTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }
        };
        TopSPPanel.Children.Add(NewQuestion_BTN);

        LowerPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10);
        Border LowerNewQuestion_BTN = AddBorder("+", 24);
        LowerNewQuestion_BTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            string InputText = CreateInputWindow("What is the name of the button you wish to create?");
            Border ChooseQuestionBTN = AddBorder(LowerPanel.Children.Count + ". " + InputText, 16);
            ChooseQuestionBTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
            {
                UncheckAllButtons();
                ChooseQuestionBTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
                NavigateToPage(MainButtonText, InputText);
            };
            LowerPanel.Children.Insert(LowerPanel.Children.Count - 1, ChooseQuestionBTN);
        };

        Border SampleQuestionBTN = AddBorder(LowerPanel.Children.Count + 1 + ". " + SecondaryButtonText, 16);
        SampleQuestionBTN.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate
        {
            UncheckAllButtons();
            SampleQuestionBTN.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
            NavigateToPage(MainButtonText, SecondaryButtonText);
        };
        LowerPanel.Children.Insert(LowerPanel.Children.Count, SampleQuestionBTN);

        LowerPanel.Children.Add(LowerNewQuestion_BTN); TopSPPanel.Children.Add(LowerPanel);
        LeftPanel.Children.Insert(ButtonCount, TopBorder);
        ButtonCount++;
    }

    private void UncheckAllButtons()
    {
        foreach (Border _BR in LeftPanel.Children)
        {
            if (_BR.Child is StackPanel)
            {
                StackPanel SP = (StackPanel)_BR.Child;
                foreach (UIElement UE in SP.Children)
                {
                    if (UE is StackPanel)
                    {
                        StackPanel SP1 = (StackPanel)UE;
                        foreach (Border B in SP1.Children)
                        {
                            B.Background = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I will test this method tomorrow and I will write to you.

Comment: Everything works, thanks